# android firestore: retrieve custom object from HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to store userdata in a document in Firestore. To do that I’m using a HashMap:

```
                String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    User user = new User(stringMail, stringUsername, stringGender, stringBirthday,
                            stringCountry, registeredOn);

                    HashMap<String, User> userHashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    userHashMap.put("userdata", user);

                    users.document(userID).set(userHashMap, SetOptions.merge())
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Upload completed to Firestore!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

That works pretty good. I do have a problem though with retrieving the data. As the data is stored in a HashMap I can’t use following code:

```
String userID = mAuth.getUid(); 
users.document(userID).get() 
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() { 
            @Override 
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) { 
                Map<String, Object> userHashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
                userHashMap = documentSnapshot.getData(); 
                User user = (User) userHashMap.get("userdata");
```

I also can't use:

```
User user = documentSnapshot.toObject(User.class);
```

So I wondered whether someone can suggest a way how to retrieve a custom object from a HashMap? I should also mention that the document will contain a second HashMap.

Comment: The Firestore SDK currently doesn't support fetching strongly typed document fields.  You will have to manually map the `userdata` field object data into a java User object.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So basically I would have to do it like this?
`User user = new User();
user.setEmail(documentSnapshot.getString("userdata.email"));
user.setUsername(documentSnapshot.getString("userdata.username"));`

Comment: That would be one way to do it, yes.  Or you can get the userdata Map out of the document, then look at its fields directly.

Comment: How can I look directly to the filds of the hashmap? Using this code isn't working: 
`System.out.println("username: " + userHashMap.get("userdata").getValue("username"));`

Comment: can we see your model class please